# Maximum length of a rain chain

Tags: water, drainage, gutters, rain

Can I hang a rain chain with cups from a gutter on a two story house?  Will it get too heavy when it rains?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the water flows right through; the "cups" are funnels to recapture spray. I wouldn't worry about it.

I would be more focused on where the water was going to go when it got to ground level.